# Rewrite Model and Interface not working for newly added methods

Tags: api, model, magento2.1.6

I want to add country name in the address list of customers/me rest api.

I have tried adding my changes in core files and I got the desired result. But when I try to rewrite, it doesn't work.

Can anyone please check and help me with this?

**etc/di.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Address" type="Company\Module\Model\Data\Customer\Address"/>    
</config>
```

**Address.php file:**

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Model\Data\Customer;

use \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory;

class Address extends \Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Address implements \Company\Module\Api\Data\Customer\AddressInterface
{

    /**
     * Locale model
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\ListsInterface
     */
    protected $_localeLists;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory
     * @param AttributeValueFactory $attributeValueFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
            AttributeValueFactory $attributeValueFactory, 
            \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface $metadataService,
            \Magento\Framework\Locale\ListsInterface $localeLists,
            $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_localeLists = $localeLists;
        parent::__construct($extensionFactory, $attributeValueFactory, $metadataService, $data);
    }


    /**
     * Get Country name
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getCountryName()
    {
        $country_id = $this->getCountryId();
        $country_name = (string) $this->_localeLists->getCountryTranslation($country_id);
        return $country_name;
    }

}
```

---

**AddressInterface file:**

```
<?php 

namespace Company\Module\Api\Data\Customer;


/**
 * Customer address interface.
 * @api
 */

interface AddressInterface extends \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface
{

    /**
     * Country Name from Country Id
     *
     * @return string|null
     */

    public function getCountryName();       

}
```

---

when I use any existing function from parent model file and do changes in it, it works. So I think rewrite is working fine. But it doesn't work for the newly added function.

Comment: Any body on this issue please ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow magento Docs as they are defined good way to add new field in address form.

```
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html
```